# Examine the convergence of $\left({\cos n\over n}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Examine the convergence of $$\left\langle{\cos n\over n}\right\rangle$$

I attempted to show that the given sequence is a cauchy sequence.

given $\epsilon>0$ there exists $m>0$ such that

$$|{\cos n\over n}-{\cos m\over m}|=|{\cos n\over n}|+|{\cos m\over m}|\le{1\over n}+{1\over m}<{2\over m}<\epsilon$$

So we are able to find an $m$ for which the condition will be satisfied. Hence the given sequence is a cauchy sequence and so convergent.

Does it look good ?

Comment: If you need a proof from definition, you probably have the right general idea. It is not well expressed, and might get almost no marks on a test.

Comment: so how should i put it ?

Comment: You need to start by saying that you will show that for every $\epsilon \gt 0$, there is an $N$ such that if $m$ and $n$ are $\gt N$, then $|f(m)-f(n)|\lt \epsilon$. Then observe that $|f(m)-f(n)|\le |f(m)|+|f(n)|$. (You asserted equality.) Then observe that if $m,n\gt N$ then $|f(m)|\lt \frac{1}{N}$, same for the other. Then say that if we choose $N$ say the smallest integer $\gt \frac{2}{\epsilon}$, the inequality will hold.

Comment: And if you do not need to proceed from the definition, use Squueezing.

Comment: got it ! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1:**
$$a_n=<{\cos n\over n}>$$ Then $$a_n=\frac{1}{n}.\cos n$$
The first tends to zero and the second is bounded. So $(a_n)$  converges to $0$.

**Method 2:**
$$-\frac{1}{n}\leq a_n\leq \frac{1}{n}$$
and apply [squeeze theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem).

**Method 3:**
You showed that $a_n$ is a Cauchy sequence. Since $\mathbb R$ is complete, $a_n$ converges.

Answer (score 1):

On the other hand, taking the inverse Fourier transform of $$\hat{f}(n)=\frac{1}{n}$$ yields $$f(x)=-\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\text{sgn}(x).$$

Standard theory of Fourier analysis then implies that $$\sum\frac{\cos nx}{n}$$ converges, in particular for $x=1$.